# My Camera (In Unity) Is Tilting When My Character Moves (2D)

Tags: unity, 2d, cinemachine

I'm trying to use Cinemachine to follow my player and whenever the player moves left or right everything shifts. I'm not sure whats causing this. I have tried giving the camera a Rigidbody2D and locking the Z. This did not work. I have attached what I think may be the appropriate settings. If you know whats causing this please leave me a comment.
[image: Camera Settings]

[image: Cinemachine Settings 1 of 2]

[image: Cinemachine Settings 2 of 2]
[image: Weird] 
[image: Normal]

Comment: It looks like you've configured the Cinemachine script as one would for a 3D game - where it yaws to look in the direction the player is moving using its Aim behaviour - instead of [using pure translation as one would normally do for a 2D game](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/07/17/cinemachine-for-2d-tips-and-tricks/)

Comment: @DMGregory thank you so much! This completely fixed my issue!

Comment: (Also, for future reference: I've never used Cinemachine. I was able to find that link just by searching "unity cinemachine 2d platformer" — so don't underestimate your ability to find your own solutions with a quick bit of research!)

Answer (score 1):

Delete your Cinemachine camera. Go to **Cinemachine > Create 2D Camera**.
Now input your settings. The issue will now be resolved. 
The issue was you most likely clicked any of the other choice than Create 2D Camera in the drop down.

[This][1]https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/07/17/cinemachine-for-2d-tips-and-tricks/
is a good resource to use if you have any other troubles.